# Not Being Able to use ENV variables in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, symfony, environment-variables

i want to put the url in a env file, but when i do that i get a html object back and not my json object it also says my REACT_APP__API_URL is undefined? but i defined it in the root directory of my project in a .env file. When i hardcode the url again it works fine. i am using REACT and SYMFONY 6.2 as my api.

MY REACT CODE

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import brand from 'boss-api/dummy/brand';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { SourceReader, PapperBlock } from 'boss-components';
import { EditableCellDemo, EditableCellFrmDemo } from './demos';
import axios from 'axios';
import { EditDocuments } from '../../components/EditDocuments';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import { Modal, Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { EditorState } from 'draft-js';


const styles = ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  button: {
    margin: '1rem',
  },
  modal: {
    margin: 'auto',
    maxWidth: 600,
    width: '90%',
    height: '100%'
  },
  paper: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    boxShadow: '5px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',
    padding: '2rem',
    borderRadius: '5px',
  },
  textField: {
    marginBottom: '1rem',
  },
});

function Documents(props) {
  const title = brand.name + ' - Table';
  const description = brand.desc;
  const docSrc = 'containers/Tables/demos/';
  const { classes } = props;
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([]);
  const [documentTitle, setTitleSearch] = useState('');
  const [newDocuments, setNewDocument] = useState({
    document_title: '',
    document_status: '',
    });

    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/getDocuments`, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL)
        setDocuments(response.data.document);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }, []);
```

my .env file

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

UPDATE
i changed my .env file to .env.production name

this is a screenshot of my directories [image]

and this is my package.json with the scripts

````
 "build": "env-cmd .env cross-env NODE_ENV=production NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color --progress",
```

``` 
"start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider node server --dotenv",

   "build:dll": "node ./internals/scripts/dependencies.js",
```

the react code stayed the same
````

Comment: It's a common misconception that React handles environment file parsing. In actuality, this is handled by your bundler/build system. Are you perchance using webpack or something else?

Comment: did you use create react app?

Comment: i bought a template called boss-ultimate on theme-forest. it uses webpack 5

Answer (score 1):

The code is working, try to using different `.env.development` file (editor mode) and `.env.production` file (release mode). Remember to terminate server and restart again.

Comment: That didnt work sadly i still get undefined when i console.log process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL

Comment: i also updated my question with new info

Comment: @adnanebds I think you misunderstand. Use .env.development, not .env.production while developing.

Answer (score 0):

The Fix was adding it in my webpack config file as plugin, since i am using webpack 5 as u can see below

```
 new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      NODE_ENV: 'development',
    }),
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      REACT_APP_API_URL: 'https://127.0.0.1:8000',
    }),
```